# Enter button does not submit form (IE ONLY) ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, internet-explorer, textbox

I have a form with a textbox and a button. IE is the only browser that will not submit the form when Enter is pressed (works in FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome, etc.).  I found this javascript function to try to coax IE into behaving; but no avail:

```
function checkEnter(e){
    var characterCode
    if (e && e.which) {
        e = e
        characterCode = e.which
    } else {
        e = event
        characterCode = e.keyCode
    }
    if (characterCode == 13) {
        document.forms[0].submit()
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
searchbox.Attributes("OnKeyUp") = "checkEnter(event)"
```

Any advice?

**EDIT:** [This page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/EnterKeyToButtonClick.aspx) on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/) outlines what Dillie was saying, and it works perfectly.

Comment: So, your form has no buttons at all?

Comment: Sorry, it has a button as well.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The other thing I have done in the past is wrap the form area in a Panel and set the DefaultButton attribute to the submit button you have. This effectively maps the enter key to the submission as long as you have a form element in focus in the panel area.

Comment: Nope, it wont (answered my own question).  This worked, thanks! :D

Comment: Glad it worked. The nice caveat with this too is that if you have multiple forms on the page (say various options to search by), you can wrap a panel around each one of them and then the proper submit button is properly "mapped".

Comment: this solution creates a javascript function. Is there a way to solve this problem so that its accessible?

Answer (score 25):

Just create a text input in a hidden div on the page. This will circumvent the IE bug.

Example div:

```
    <!-- Fix for IE bug (One text input and submit, disables submit on pressing "Enter") -->
    <div style="display:none">
            <input type="text" name="hiddenText"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a good write up of this problem here, and a nice jquery based solution:

> http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/submit-a-form-in-ie-with-enter

Answer (score 2):

```
// Use the following Javascript in your HTML view
// put it somewhere between <head> and </head>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"><!--
    function KeyDownHandler(btn)
    {
      if (event.keyCode == 13)
      {
        event.returnValue=false;
        event.cancel = true;
        btn.click();
      }
    }
    // -->
    </script>

    // Put this in your TextBox(es) aka inside <asp:textbox ... >
    onkeydown="KeyDownHandler(ButtonID)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, it throws a lovely 'Object doesn't support this property or method' error, however :(

Answer (score 1):

When using `display:none`, IE won't see the button and therefore won't be able to use it to submit the form. Instead, you could use `z-index` and absolute positioning to hide it under another element, e.g. with the style:

`position:absolute; bottom: -20px; left: -20px; z-index: -1;`

Now it'll still be there, usable by IE, but hidden beneath another element.

Answer (score 1):

Hide the button - not using display:none, but with the following styles:

```
position: absolute; /* no longer takes up layout space */
visibility: hidden; /* no longer clickable / visible */
```

If you do this, you won't need to add any other elements or hidden inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a peculiarity in IE for single text field inputs.

A simple solution is to stop the page having a single text field by adding another hidden one.

```
<input type="text" name="hidden" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;" />
```

see.. 
https://web.archive.org/web/20210125133120/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060805-1.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Does it use a GET instead of a POST?  Is the URL too long?   I've seen that...

Answer (score -1):

Basically, a form needs either a button, input type="submit" or an input type="image" to enable the builtin behaviour to submit a form on enter. You shouldn't need a javascript to submit it.