# ASP.NET Enter key

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a master page and based on that master page I created a page with a TextBox and two Validation controls for `RequiredValidator` and `RegularExpressionValidator` and one `ValidationSummary`.

when pressing the enter key in TextBox, I expected that both validator show their errorMessage on validationSummary but thats not what happening it only works when I press the button on page.

According to this page I wrapped my code with `<asp:panel>` and a `DefaultButton` attribute but it didn't solve the problem.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnet_Enter_key_problem.aspx

I want to know what the problem here is and whether there is any workaround?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

    **<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="EmailSend">**
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="EmailValidation" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification"
                ValidationGroup="EmailValidation" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 76px">
                Email:
            </td>
            <td class="style1">
                <asp:TextBox ID="EmailForget" runat="server" Width="244px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequiered" runat="server" ControlToValidate="EmailForget"
                    CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup="EmailValidation">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="EmailRegular" runat="server" ControlToValidate="EmailForget"
                    CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="email required"
                    ValidationGroup="EmailValidation">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 76px">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td class="style1">
                <asp:Button ID="EmailSend" runat="server" Text="send" Width="56px" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   **<asp:Panel>**
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: have you tried adding the validation group to the asp:button as well?

Comment: You have missed a <td> tag around your ValidationSummary control, add it first !

Comment: @Jacques yes I have add asp:button to Validation group

Comment: @Nalaka526 there is td tag in my real code. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (document.addEventListener) {//if Firefox
        document.addEventListener("keypress", fireFoxHandler, true);
    } else {
    document.attachEvent("onkeyup", ieHandler);
    }

    function fireFoxHandler(evt) {            
        if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
            document.getElementById("EmailSend").click();
        }
    }

    function ieHandler(evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
            document.getElementById("EmailSend").click();
        }
    }

</script>
```

Found this solution [**here**](http://forums.asp.net/t/1442764.aspx/1). 
(I didn't check this in MasterPage scenario, please check...)

Comment: @Nalaka525 Thanks a lot it worked even in MasterPage scenario.

Comment: I found this http://forums.asp.net/t/1100563.aspx/1 which explains why ValidationSummary and Enter key doesn't work together.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE then according to the answers on these two pages:

[ASP.NET enter key and form submit with no javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706625/asp-net-enter-key-and-form-submit-with-no-javascript)

[Enter button does not submit form (IE ONLY) ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270494/enter-button-does-not-submit-form-ie-only-asp-net)

you only need to add the following to your form

```
<!-- Fix for IE bug submit on pressing "Enter") -->
<div style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="hiddenText"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
But no the same problem exist with chrome and Firefox too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
textboxusername.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", "javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13)       __doPostBack('" + LinkButton1.UniqueID + "','')");
    textboxpassword.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", "javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13)   __doPostBack('" + LinkButton1.UniqueID + "','')");
}
```

and this is the link..

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" class="btn" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply i tried ur script but it didnt work.
I also add this two line on page loadPage. 
Form.DefaultButton = EmailSend.UniqueID;
Page.Form.DefaultFocus = EmailForget.ClientID;
and it also didnt work.