# asp.net required field validator disables enter button form submission

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

We have a form with a number of required fields.  When I am on a required field and I hit the enter key the form does not submit.  However, if I'm on a field that is not required, hitting the enter key does submit the form.  This is problematic because submitting the form is what fires the validation to display the validation summary at the top.  If I'm on a required field it doesn't fire this validation.  It does seem to fire it's own validation and display my error text (which is just an asterisk) but people are not seeing this.

Does anyone know why a non-required field enter key would submit the form but a required field enter key wouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described, it sounds like you're using server-side validation. Try setting `EnableClientScript` to false on the validator, which will disable client-side validation.

If this is not enough, you can override the validation when the submit button is clicked like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    validateForm = function(){
        var isValid = Page_ClientValidate("");
        if (isValid){
            //some custom logic if needed
        }
        return true; //do the postback even if validation fails?
                     //otherwise return isValid
    }
</script>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return validateForm();" ... />
```

Comment: I'm using both server and client side validation.  I don't understand why I wouldn't want to use client side validation?  When I set the validator's client side validation to false I then have no required fields submitting the form.  That's not the idea either.  I just expect that any field except a textarea field would submit the form when hitting enter regardless of whether it's required or not.

Comment: That's why I provided an example that allows you to manipulate the validation process to suite your needs.

Comment: So are you saying that rather than having all fields submit the form, make it so that none submit it and the only way to submit it is to click the button?

Comment: I don't really know what I'm saying. I'm just going based off of your question, and giving you an option to work around the validator that's causing problems. Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: I literally have almost 100 fields on this form which may or may not have validators (depending on our customer's preferences).  So it's not one validator that's causing the problem.  It's all validators that won't allow it's cooresponding field to submit the form.

Comment: See if this helps at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293278/asp-net-enter-key

Comment: I ended up putting a jquery listener on any input text to catch the return key and click the button.  That works now to fire the validation no matter what kind of field they're on (required or not).  Thanks.