# Enter key wont submit form in IE6

Tags: javascript, html, security, browser, forms

I have a form like this:

```
<form id="form_main" name="form_main" action="/search/" target="iframe001" method="get" onSubmit="reset_and_subm();">
```

Enter key wont submit this form in IE6, but will in Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari, and IE8 (haven't tested IE7 yet).
**IN FACT, NOT EVEN PRESSING THE SUBMIT BUTTON SUBMITS THE FORM.**
I have tried for hours now... What could be the problem?
I have tried this:

```
<form id="form_main" name="form_main" action="/search/" target="iframe001" method="get" onSubmit="alert('hello');">
```

And the alertbox comes up with the message...

Now here is the function "reset_and_subm();"

```
function reset_and_subm(){
    document.getElementById("p").value = 1;
    return true;
}
```

Does anybody know what I should do here?

Btw, I have checked all inputs in the form, and all seem okay... So assume there is nothing wrong with the content of the form.

Thanks

UPDATE:

I have a submit button yes.
The entire form content is way to large to put here, but it contains only one textfield.
The rest is "selects" and "hidden inputs".
I am pressing enter in the only textfield there is...
Also I have added the code of the submit button:

```
<input name="nav_querystring" type="text" id="nav_querystring" style="width: 240px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" value="">

<input type="submit" name="nav_submit" id="nav_submit" value="Sök" style="width: 55px; font-size: 13px;">
```

UPDATE2:

Just to point out, I have included the js file which contains the function "reset_and_subm" and also, I am using mod_rewrite in .htaccess to rewrite the action of the form.
I hope none of this is causing the issue.

UPDATE3:
Seems the problem might lie in the body OnLoad eventy, where I have a js function not listed here.
Doesn't IE6 support OnLoad?
What should I use instead...

Here is my current code:

```
  <body onLoad="subSelection();">
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the full code of the form please? In which field are you pressing the enter key? Do you have a submit button?

Comment: [this self-contained example](http://jsfiddle.net/qJgHf/) shows the code you have works fine in IE6, your problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Okay, I will keep looking then. Thanks Andy...

Comment: Not sure how helpful it is but I tend to use jQuery (http://jquery.com/) to stop me having to worry about whether IE6 does onload the same way as other browsers. Might not be an option for you but if you do a lot of JS I think its a great thing to use anyway. :)

Comment: It would be a mistake to support IE6 because everyone who is running it has been hacked many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made two changes to your code.

As you are calling a function from onsubmit, I have included the "return" keyword in the method call.

As the form only has one form element, I have added a hidden element to the form.

```
<form id="form_main" name="form_main" action="/search/" target="iframe001" method="get" onSubmit="return reset_and_subm();">
    <div style="display: none;"><input type="text" name="ie6"></div>
    <input name="nav_querystring" type="text" id="nav_querystring" style="width: 240px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="nav_submit" id="nav_submit" value="Sök" style="width: 55px; font-size: 13px;">
</form>
```

Please shout if you are still stuck.

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck... This is one of those creepy errors which will take a loooong time to find. Is there any good IE6 debugging tool anywhere?

Comment: Do a search for IE Developer Tools, it is a bit like Firebug for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember there is a strange bug with only one text box on a page in IE6 that we had to work around a long time ago. Try putting another empty textbox on the page with its style set to display: none and see if that works. It might sound crazy but that's what happens with crazy IE bugs...

Comment: Tried it, but didn't solve the problem... Thanks anyways Chris.

Comment: @Camran: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270494/enter-button-does-not-submit-form-ie-only-asp-net/487965#487965 seems to be what I was struggling for. Maybe you need to have it in a hidden div rather than being hidden itself. There are other options on that page that might help too.

Comment: Chris, thanks alot for your help... Check my third update, might be the problem here... I will meanwhile look into the question you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in IE where forms with a single text field won't submit when pressing the "enter/return" key. The solution is to add a second field :

Simples :D

Comment: I've heard of this - just add a hidden field